# node.js / npm - override local default modules directory (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower, npm-install

Let's say I don't want to install my local (per project) packages in node_modules - I'd like to have it under `sources/node_modules` instead of just `node_modules`. Is it possible to override it just like you can do in bower?

In bower you provide `.bowerrc` file with `directory` option, see [docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/). It works exactly as if you had `bower_components locally` - no additional files, loaders, nothing at all - just the container dir is different.

Comment: Sure, just do `npm install --prefix /sources/node_modules <package>` or create a symlink

Comment: @adeneo mhm, yeah, I found that, sorry not to mention that. Regarding your suggestion - will those packages be available to files that just call `require`, just like they would with standard `node_modules`?

Comment: It will if you do `require('/sources/node_modules/module')`

Comment: There used to be a `require.paths`, but looks like it's deprecated, there's probably a substitute

Comment: You could also create an environment variable flag, and use it like this: `require(process.env.MY_FLAG || 'my_module');`

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
$ mkdir -p sources
$ ln -s package.json sources/package.json
$ npm install --prefix sources/
$ export NODE_PATH="`pwd`/sources"
```

## Explanation

You can (as @adeneo mentioned) simply install packages to any folder with:

```
$ npm install --prefix sources/ my-package
```

This will install to `sources/my-package`. However, this solution is far from neat in two ways:

### package.json

It sounds as though, rather than installing individual packages, what you really want to do is install everything in `package.json` to the `sources/` folder. The problem is that when you do `npm install --prefix sources/`, it also looks for `package.json` in the `sources/` folder. If that works for you, then great.

The only way I've found to keep your `package.json` in your project root and install node modules somewhere else is to symlink the local `package.json` into that directory:

```
$ mkdir -p sources
$ ln -s package.json sources/package.json
$ npm install --prefix sources
```

### require

As you mentioned, you will probably want your scripts to be able to require modules like normal - `require('my-module')` rather than `require('sources/my-module')`.

[The `NODE_PATH` environment variable](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_addenda_package_manager_tips) can help here:

```
$ export NODE_PATH=`pwd`/sources/node_modules
$ node -e "require('my-module')"  # Success
```

There is an important caveat: `node` will look for modules in a specific order:

1. In a `node_modules` folder in the local directory
2. In a `node_modules` folder in the parent directory, then its parent etc.
3. In paths in the `NODE_PATH`, if it hasn't found the module yet

So be careful there are aren't any other `node_modules` folders in the current or any parent directory which mention your modules, or things could get quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Create local_modules in your root directory and add package.json "@amazon/product-module": "file:local_modules/@amazon/product-module",

```
file structure
local_modules
   @amazon (folder)
     product-module (folder)
       [add your file which overrides]
```

Now do npm update and you will get your local_modules/@amazon/product-module file into node_module/@amazon/product-module